# Posting images to Facebook/Twitter via Sharekit for Phonegap?

Tags: facebook, image, cordova, twitter, sharekit

is it possible to share images from camera/gallery to Facebook/Twitter in a Phonegap app with the ShareKit plugin? Is it possible to do it with any other plugin? I see that Facebook Connect does not have that option, how do phonegap developers deal with this situation?

Regards, Jasha